# How to override a single function in a package for internal use with laravel?

Tags: laravel, package

I would like to override a function in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php`

or to be precise a function iside the trait `Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesEchos.php` used by that file. However I could not find very clear information on how to override packages. Could someone please help me understand how.

I understand that I need to extend BladeCompiler

Let's call it MyBladeCompiler

```
class MyBladeCompiler extends BladeCompiler
{
    public function compileEchoDefaults($value)
    {
        return 'test';
        return preg_replace('/^(?=\$)(.+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/si', 'isset($1) ? $1 : $2', $value);
    }
}
```

I now would like to register it as the new class to be used. I do understand this should be done in a serviceprovider, but how?

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
      $this->app->bind(BladeCompiler::class, MyBladeCompiler ::class);
    }
}
```

this does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new service provider called `ViewServiceProvider`, then in it, delete the register and boot methods, and make it extend `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider`.

Then, add this method:

```
public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
{
    // The Compiler engine requires an instance of the CompilerInterface, which in
    // this case will be the Blade compiler, so we'll first create the compiler
    // instance to pass into the engine so it can compile the views properly.
    $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
        return new MyBladeCompiler(
            $this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']
        );
    });

    $resolver->register('blade', function () {
        return new CompilerEngine($this->app['blade.compiler']);
    });
}
```

Note how in the singleton method, I'm using *your* blade compiler class.

Then, open `config/app.php`, and replace the `\Illuminate\View\BladeServiceProvider::class`, record, with your own service provider.

So the service provider should look like this:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use MyBladeCompiler
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider as BaseViewServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends BaseViewServiceProvider
{
    public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
    {
        $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
            return new MyBladeCompiler(
                $this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']
            );
        });

        $resolver->register('blade', function () {
            return new CompilerEngine($this->app['blade.compiler']);
        });
    }
}
```

This works by extending the Illuminate view service provider, so all existing methods work as expected. Then, you need to override the `registerBladeEngine()` method so that your overridden one is called, and not the one in the illuminate provider.

In your overridden method, you're specifying that your compiler should be used instead of the original one.

You then specify that your extended view service provider is used instead of the illuminate one by editing the app.php config file.